# "selector of component" not a known element despite declaration?

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular8

Within my AppModule, I transited from having a ListComponent to creating a ListModule, with declarations to ListComponent and a newly generated ListItemComponent. Within ListComponent's template, I am using the selector 'app-list-item', which is the selector of the component for ListItemComponent and which was declared in the List Module. Even so, I get the error: 'app-list-item' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-list-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module." Unsure of what I am missing.

I want it so that the ListComponent html file can call the ListItem component selector that it declared in its module.

Here is my code:

**list-item-component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-item',
  templateUrl: './list-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-item.component.scss']
})

export class ListItemComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**list-module.ts**:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import {ListItemComponent} from './list-item/list-item.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:[ CommonModule ],
    declarations:[ListComponent, ListItemComponent],
    exports:[ListComponent]
})

export class ListModule{}
```

**list-component.html (where error occurs):**

```
<app-list-item> </app-list-item>
```

**app-module.ts :**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ListModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What could be causing the error? If the ListComponent is the only one using the ListItemComponent selector within its html file, why is declaring the ListItemComponent in the List module not enough?

Comment: Have you tried exporting ListItemComponent from the ListModule?

Comment: Do you have to export it if it's only being used internally.?

Comment: That's how I've always done it for separate modules. For example, the [TableModule](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts) in PrimeNG declares and exports everything even though you only use the Table component itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I did try exporting ListItemComponent as well from the ListModule and no luck :(. I am exporting the ListComponent because eventually I will need to use that component externally.

Comment: Nothing you have shown should cause that error.  It works just fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jatj2c

Comment: So weird that I am getting this issue then...I have tried ng build and ng serve over again and still get the same error